# Nest custom exception class within class? (Python)

Tags: python, class, scope, nested, nested-class

I'd like to nest an Exception subclass within a class of my own, like so:

```
class Foo(object):

    def bar(self):
        #does something that raises MyException

    class MyException(Exception):
        pass
```

This way, I only have to import Foo (and not MyException) when calling bar() from another module. But what I have below doesn't work:

```
from foo_module import Foo

foo = Foo()

try:
    foo.bar()
except Foo.MyException as e:
    print e
```

Python gives this error:

> type object 'Foo' has no attribute 'MyException'

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? I just fired up IDLE for Python 2.7.2, defined a class with a nested exception class and a method that raised the nested exception, and then tried a try/except block, and everything worked fine.

Comment: Were you doing "import foo_module" or "from foo_module import Foo"?

Comment: I didn't actually set up a separate module and import it. But I can't see how that could possibly make a difference. Either the `Foo` object has an attribute `MyException`, or it doesn't. Conceivably a nested class block might have not become an attribute of the outer class in for some obscure reason, but there's no way importing from another module it will affect what attributes it has. I suspect something else is going wrong. Can you construct a *small* test case that gives you this error when you run it and paste the **full** contents of both files here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given the contents of `t.py` of:

```
class Foo():
  def RaiseBar(self):
    raise Foo.Bar("hi")
  class Bar(Exception):
    pass
```

And running this on the python terminal:

```
>>> import t
>>> x = t.Foo()
>>> try:
...     x.RaiseBar()
... except t.Foo.Bar as e:
...     print e
... 
hi
```

Is not this exactly what you were looking for?

Not sure what you did wrong with yours, I suggest you re-examine the code more closely.

Comment: Yes, you were right. My code was a little bit off from the example I provided. My bad. :/